# How to interrupt SafeSignal in ReactiveSwift?

Tags: iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

Hi I am new to reactive swift. In my new project I am using ReactiveSwift. I am observing value by using SafeSignal variable. I want to interrupt the signal before getting the value. Please help me out in this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when you `observe` on a `Signal` or `start` a `SignalProducer`, you will get a `Disposable` back.

This can be used to end the observation:

```
let property = MutableProperty<Int>(0)
let signalDisposable = property.signal.observeValues {
  print("Signal: \($0)")
}

let producerDisposable = property.producer.startWithValues {
  print("Producer: \($0)")
}


property.value = 1            // Signal and Producer receive value 1
signalDisposable?.dispose()   // End signal observation
property.value = 2            // Only producer receives value 2
producerDisposable.dispose()  // End producer observation
property.value = 3            // No one receives value 3
```

### Cancelation of running work

If you're creating your own `SignalProducer` for some (longer) work, you'll have to keep disposal in mind in order to stop ongoing work:

```
let performNetworkCall = SignalProducer<Data, Error> { (observer, disposable) in
  let url = URL(string: "https://www.download.com")!
  let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, _, error) in
    // Handle completion
  })
  downloadTask.resume()
  disposable.observeEnded {
    // Cancel the download on disposal!
    downloadTask.cancel()
  }
}
```

Otherwise, your observer will be detached, but the work started by the observer will still resume